# Best approach to map data of variable length to a fixed structure?

Tags: java, android, sql, data-mapping

Given a fixed target data table such as, e.g.

```
 1      2         3       4      5
 Spain, Portugal, France, Italy, Greece
```

the input consists of data columns plus a configurable list of enabled columns such as `[1, 4]` i.e. the input might only contain `Spain` and `Italy`.

The purpose is to build an SQL statement (*although it's not an SQL question per se*) that will only set the columns that are available in the input to their correct positions.

Possible input:

```
enabled columns: 2,4,5
data:
    p1    i1    g1
    p2    i2    g2
    .............
```

Attempting to do this programmatically (in java), not in SQL, and not quite sure how to avoid crazy branching of `if`'s and `else`'s.

The question is not just about this specific case, and is not really sql or another programming language, but rather about how to map variable inputs to a fixed output given a definition of some form, e.g. indices in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have not misunderstood your question, you want generate a sequence of INSERT INTO commands in SQL, to add new tuples to a table, holding the fileds that are not passed in the input of your program with some default value (e.g. NULL). So, in your example, you want generate the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE_NAME(NULL,p1,NULL,i1,g1);
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE_NAME(NULL,p2,NULL,i2,g2);
```

Then, this function can be implemented as follows:

```
    public static String insertOptional(int[] inputColumns, String[][] data) {
        // start of the simple algorithm
        final String tableName = "YOUR_TABLE_NAME";
        final int columnsOfTable = 5; // as in your example

        StringBuilder sqlStatement = new StringBuilder();

        for (String[] tuple : data) {
            sqlStatement.append("INSERT INTO ")
                    .append(tableName)
                    .append("(");
            int inputColumnIndex = 0;
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnsOfTable; columnIndex++) {
                if (columnIndex == inputColumns[inputColumnIndex]) {
                    sqlStatement.append(tuple[inputColumnIndex]);
                    inputColumnIndex++;
                } else {
                    // replace "NULL" with your default value for
                    // fields that are not given as input
                    sqlStatement.append("NULL");
                }
                if (columnIndex < columnsOfTable)
                    sqlStatement.append(",");
            }
            sqlStatement.append(");\n");
        }
        return sqlStatement.toString();
    }
```

and, your example can be executed as follows:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] inputColumns = { 2, 4, 5 };
        String[][] data = { { "p1", "i1", "g1" }, { "p2", "i2", "g2" } };
        String sqlStatement = insertOptional(inputColumns, data);
        System.out.println(sqlStatement);
    }
```

This main method prints exactly what I thought you expect:

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE_NAME(NULL,p1,NULL,i1,g1);
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE_NAME(NULL,p2,NULL,i2,g2);
```